# Translating mouse X & Y to 3D model coordinates

Tags: mouseover, hittest, mouse-picking

I'm building a simple 3D drag and drop interface in processing, and want to detect when the mouse rolls over an object. I would imagine that I need to do some matrix translations to the 3D model coordinates to get them into screen space and so on ...

I have a simple version of this working, the problem is that when camera is moved around the scene the coordinates I get go haywire.

So how do I translate the tile coordinates into screen space (since the screenX & screenY aren't working properly)?

**UPDATE:**
I eventually found two examples from the Processing site on how to do this. Thanks to *villintehaspam*.

http://processing.org/hacks/hacks:picking

Comment: To see a 2-D projection of your 3-D object, you have to translate from 3-D coordinates to a specific 2-D projection (screen coordinates). Problem is that this translation involves loss, so you can't just reverse the process and get a 3-D point. You have to project a ray backward, find all of the objects that the ray intersects, and sort by Z-order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called picking. Search for mouse picking and you get lots and lots of hits.

Basic theory is this:

1. Get x,y coords from the mouse click.
2. Convert these to x,y,z coordinates in eye coordinates (i.e -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= y <= 1, z=near/far clip distance, if you have a normal projection).
3. Transform these coordinates by the inverse of the projection matrix to get world coordinates.
4. You now have a ray from the camera position, with the direction towards the world coordinates you just got.
5. Make a ray-object intersection test with the objects you want to consider. Choose the object that intersects the ray that is closest to the ray origin (camera position).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It turns out there's already code for this (not surprisingly) I just couldn't find it. Having the right search term helped.